# How to create a condition to obtain an automatic object property relation in Protege?

Tags: ontology, protege, reasoning

I'm doing a project in Protege on the ontology related to the university problem.
I have some classes and object properties relations between them:

[image: Diagram]

As depicted, there are several classes and relations. My issue is, how (and where) to write the condition to obtain the automatic inference that, if all blue-arrow relations are satisfied by the individual, the red-arrow relation must be also satisfied (thus it is inferred then by the reasoner)?

I will appreciate any help!
Thanks.
Hubert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use SWRL. On the SWRL tab, type the following:

```
isTakingCourse(?s, ?c) ^ hasModule(?c, ?m) ^ isExamOn(?e, ?m) -> takesExam(?s, ?e)
```

**Option 2**

Use property chains and inverse properties. In the Description view, declare `takesExam` to be a *super*property of:

```
isTakingCourse o hasModule o inverse isExamOn
```