# How can I represent the following in an ontology using Protege?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ontology, semantic-web, protege

**∀Defense_Argument, OldCase, NewCase,
applied_to(Defense_Argument, OldCase),
similar_to(OldCase, NewCase) ⇒ applied_to(Defense_Argument, NewCase).**

I want to represent this using Protege. Thanks in advance.

Comment: SWRL or property chains, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64828565/7879193

Comment: Thanks. But could you please let me know how I can represent it using Protege ontology editor?

Comment: On *SWRL Tab* or *Description View*.